Why does last() selects two tags in the following XML?
Given the following XML:
<app>
    <welcome-message>Hi! This is xpather beta...</welcome-message>
    <abstract>
        This web app enables you to query XML/HTML documents with your
        browser in real time. It can generate queries for you too! 
    </abstract>
    <description>
        <subject>
            To generate an xpath query for a specific element,
            please hold CTRL and hover over it.
            An xpath is generated heuristically with the aim
            to be unambiguous and the shortest possible.
        </subject>
      <note>hey</note>
    </description>
    <extra-notes>
        <note>
            By default XML mode is used but if a document cannot
            be parsed as XML then HTML mode kicks in.
        </note>
        <note>
            Pasting documents bigger than 500kb may cause your
            browser become sluggish or unresponsive.
        </note>
    </extra-notes>
</app>

The following Xpath: //note[last()]
Returns two tags: the last one in <description>, and the last one in <extra-notes>.
But why is that? Does last() not operate on the set of nodes from previous axis?
//note should give us a set of nodes, and from that we should be able to select the last one.

Use (//note)[last()] or descendant::note[last()], your attempt is evaluated as/is a shorthand for /descendant-or-self::node()/note[last()].

Can you explain why is it evaluated as such? I know the answer is probably "it's just the way the syntax is", but doesn't the predicate operate over the set of nodes we got in //note? I would've thought (//note)[last()] is the default behavior

Well, read the spec if you want an "explanation", https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev clearly states: "// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/. For example, //para is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/child::para" and "The location path //para[1] does not mean the same as the location path /descendant::para[1]. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents."

It's basically a question of operator priorities: //note[last()] means //(note[last()]) rather than (//note)[last()]. That might not be what you would have guessed, but relying on guesswork isn't generally advisable.
